# Where does AD specify it's external DNS servers

Tags: windows, active-directory

We have a Windows 2008R2 domain and am looking to change the external DNS servers however I cannot find where these are configured?

In the DNS settings, I have no forwarders configured however it must be configured somewhere as everything works.

Does AD send requests that cannot be resolved locally to the gateway and then it uses it's DNS servers from there, meaning to change the external DNS servers it should be changed on the gateway/router?

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of forwarders, by default the server will use the root hints, which should have been apparent to you if you were looking at the forwarders configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It use the forwarder, and if none is there it use the dns listed onto your NIC card to reach another DNS server.

Please note the computers might use other DNS setting too, it depend on your DHCP you push to them

Comment: Yes, PCs use AD DC for DNS. AD DC has no forwarders so must be using router DNS.

Comment: Source? AFAIK it doesn't. If there's no forwarders it either is allowed to use root hints or fails.

Comment: @EsaJokinen In 2008R2 I seen it working, can't tell for newer OS. Mostly due to bad setup. I seen a lot of junior admin that did setup no forwarder at all, and did not tick the option like joeqwerty's wrote, and on the server NIC itselft they put the ISP DNS's server there as secondary, and they setup the DHCP to give in secondary that ISP DNS. I dont tell it's a good thing, but it kind of work, even if a bad setup.

Comment: @Dercni The DNS packet dont decide to go magicly to the router. Its on the NIC itself or check joeqwerty's answer.